# Does a map-only UDF benefit from being Algebraic or Accumulative?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

In Pig on Hadoop I have a Java UDF being applied to big tuples which just takes 4 fields of the big tuple and (after some nontrivial calculation) returns two new values which I tack onto the big tuple.

There is no reduce phase.

> Can this benefit from being made Algebraic, or Accumulative?

In the absence of any grouping, I don't see how it would result in a speed improvement.  And it seems like grouping just to try and get a speedup is a giant leap in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you are creating a regular `EvalFunc`. It does not make sense to make it `Algebraic` or `Accumulative`.

[LOWER](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/LOWER.html) or [REGEX_EXTRACT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/REGEX_EXTRACT.html) are examples for other `EvalFunc` that do not implement any of the interfaces you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The `Algebraic` interface works by utilizing Hadoop's combiner, which is like a mini-reduce phase before the real reduce phase. Therefore, if you are not actually doing any reducing, this interface is irrelevant.

`Accumulator`, on the other hand, is not necessarily tied to a reduce phase. It is simply a method for processing very large bags in a UDF.  Often such bags are the result of grouping, but this is not necessarily the case. Instead of loading the whole bag at once, Pig will load pieces of it at a time, keeping track of what it needs to produce the final result at the end. I don't know that it's a fit for your case, but it could be used in a map-only situation.

However, you mention that you have a very large *tuple*. If you really do mean tuple, and not bag, then `Accumulator` cannot help you.

As a side note, the purpose of `Accumulator` is not to speed up computation (though this would probably be the result for bags that do fit into memory, but just barely, due to garbage collection). It is to allow you to process bags that otherwise could not be processed at all due to memory constraints. Contrast this with `Algebraic`, which really is a speed-up mechanism by reducing (ha!) the amount of data that is sent to the reducers and written to disk in the shuffle phase.